# I am not sure what I am doing wrong here LaTeX error

Tags: resume

I am currently using a template on LaTeX to build my resume so I can hopefully get a job soon! The Template in question is [this one][1]. However, when I am modifying the code to suit my needs I am getting an error like this:

```
TeX reports the error was in file: C:/Users/Beast/Desktop/git-latex/Resume.tex
```

What am I doing wrong to get this message?  Here is the code in question.

```
\documentclass[10pt,A4]{article}    


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     


\usepackage{xifthen}


\usepackage[default]{raleway}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{moresize}       



\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}      


\geometry{top=1.75cm, bottom=-.6cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}    

\usepackage{fancyhdr}               
\pagestyle{fancy}


\setlength{\headheight}{-5pt}       


\lhead{}
\chead{ \small{Name Middle Name Last Name  $\cdot$ Aspring Geologist $\cdot$   Texas, United States  $\cdot$  \textcolor{sectcol}{\textbf{@gmail.com}}  $\cdot$ xxx-xxx-xxxx}}
\rhead{}



\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}



\usepackage{multicol}           
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{%
>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%



\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
        
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, backgrounds,mindmap, trees}



\usepackage{color}


\definecolor{sectcol}{RGB}{255,150,0}


\definecolor{bgcol}{RGB}{110,110,110}


\definecolor{softcol}{RGB}{225,225,225}



\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}      


\renewcommand{\thepage}{}   

    
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}            


\newcommand{\tzlarrow}{(0,0) -- (0.2,0) -- (0.3,0.2) -- (0.2,0.4) -- (0,0.4) -- (0.1,0.2) -- cycle;}    


\newcommand{\larrow}[1]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.58]
     \filldraw[fill=#1!100,draw=#1!100!black]  \tzlarrow
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tzrarrow}{ (0,0.2) -- (0.1,0) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.2,0.2) -- (0.3,0.4) -- (0.1,0.4) -- cycle;}

%
\newcommand{\rarrow}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \filldraw[fill=sectcol!100,draw=sectcol!100!black] \tzrarrow
 \end{tikzpicture}
}




\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]
{
\colorbox{sectcol}{\mystrut \makebox[1\linewidth][l]{
\larrow{bgcol} \hspace{-8pt} \larrow{bgcol} \hspace{-8pt} \larrow{bgcol} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}\hspace{4pt}
}}\\
}



\newcommand{\metasection}[2]
{
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{p{2.4cm} p{11cm}}
\larrow{bgcol}  \normalsize{\textcolor{sectcol}{#1}}&#2\\[12pt]
\end{tabular*}
}



\newcommand{\cvevent}[5]
{
\vspace{8pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{p{2.3cm}  p{10.8cm} x{3.9cm}}
 \textcolor{bgcol}{#1}& \textbf{#2} & \vspace{2.5pt}\textcolor{sectcol}{#3}

    \end{tabular*}
\vspace{-12pt}
\textcolor{softcol}{\hrule}
\vspace{6pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{p{2.3cm} p{14.4cm}}
&        \larrow{bgcol}  #4\\[3pt]
&        \larrow{bgcol}  #5\\[6pt]
    \end{tabular*}

}

 
\newcommand{\cveventmeta}[2]
{
    \mbox{\mystrut \hspace{87pt}\textit{#1}}\\
    #2
}

\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}}


\newcommand{\lorem}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.}



\begin{document}


\pagestyle{fancy}   


\vspace{-20.55pt}

\hspace{-0.25\linewidth}\colorbox{bgcol}{\makebox[1.5\linewidth][c]{\hspace{46pt}\HUGE{\textcolor{white}{\textsc{My name Here}} } \textcolor{sectcol}{\rule[-1mm]{1mm}{0.9cm}} \parbox[b]{5cm}{ \large{ \textcolor{white}{{Aspiring Geologist}}}\\
 \large{ \textcolor{white}{{Resume}}}}






\hspace{-0.25\linewidth}\colorbox{bgcol}{\makebox[1.5\linewidth][c]{\HUGE{\textcolor{white}{\textsc{Your Name Here}} } \textcolor{sectcol}{\rule[-1mm]{1mm}{0.9cm}} \HUGE{\textcolor{white}{\textsc{Resume}} } }}





\vspace{-114pt}

\metasection{Status:}{Bachelor of Science in Geochemistry, Minor in Chemistry}
\metasection{Fields:}{Lab Technician, Security Guard} 
\metasection{Tech:}{Javascript, C++, Python, and Git }
\metasection{Loves:}{Sci-Fi series, Movies, Comic Books, Video Games, Fitness,  Programming, Learning in General. } 

\vspace{6pt}



\cvsection{Experience}


\cvevent{2016-2019}{Lab Technician}{University of Houston-Downtown}{Ensuring that the chemicals were properly filled and sealed in the correct vials}{Quality Control to ensure everything was up to Federal Regulations}




\cvevent{From when to when}{Job Title}{Describe here}{and here}



\cvevent{From when to when}{Job Title}{Describe here}{and here}


\cvevent{From when to when}{Job Title}{Describe here}{and here}




\cvevent{From when to when}{Job Title}{Describe here}{and here}



\cvsection{Education}








\cvevent{When did I go to school}{Bacholer Projects}{Describe Here}{}{}









\null
\vspace*{\fill}
\hspace{-0.25\linewidth}\colorbox{bgcol}{\makebox[1.5\linewidth][c]{\mystrut \small \textcolor{white}{} $\cdot$ \textcolor{white}{}}}




\end{document}
**strong text**
    enter code here

  [1]: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5ef649b7717bba0001d62959
```

Comment: I don't think this code is appearing to us the way it appears to you.  Could you [edit] your post and use the `{}` to make it show correctly?  Also, could you do the same with the error message?  The way the error message is formatted is an important part of what the error message is saying.

Comment: How are the colors `bgcol` and `sectcol` defined?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! I just edited the comments and just put the whole thing instead of just a snippet of it. I am using Sublime Text 3 if that matters. I've tried using Vscode but found that it was rather frustrating to not only use but set up as well for LaTeX. I may just bite the bullet and set up Linux on my computer. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You have a spurious `{` before `[c]` which causes the runaway argument, and probably after each `\large`, but one can't guess from that tangle which parts *should* be in which braces. You should use a text editor that highlights matching braces, and spread out your use in a way that it is easier to keep track of matching braces.

Comment: Hello Donald! Thank you for the input. I have tried your suggestion and it still isn't working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Red. I see your input sample is edited, but still has the two `\large{` that are unbalanced; delete the braces from them. All that negative vertical space produces over-printing; is that intentional? Probably leave out `\vspace{-114pt}` (The initial `\vspace{-20.55pt}` is ignored anyway.) Your two colored blocks have a gap, so put a little negative space between them with `\\[-??pt]%and no blank line ...\hspace...`, or leave blank lines separating them but put `\nointerlineskip` before the second block.

Comment: Hey Donald, wanted to let you know that your suggestions worked out. Thank you so much for your help and input! I also want to thank Teepeemn, and Mico for taking the time to help me out as well! I really couldn't have done this without you!